# issue with ssh-copy-id rootname@ipaddress

Tags: ssh

I am getting repeated errors whenever i am executing ssh-copy-id root@ip.
/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/aasthajainsimpl/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host 13.89.203.233 port 22: Connection timed out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6wLo.png)

Comment: Try it with `ssh -vvv <user>@host` to see more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the 13.89.203.233 host doesn't have ssh server on port 22 (or this port is behind of firewall). Try to see into sshd.conf or firewall config.
Also maybe the IP address is wrong - it belongs to Microsoft.